# setOpacity function raspberry java 1.8

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, translucency

My code sniped that sets the opacity on my JFrame works under Windows but not on my raspberry 3 that has java 1.8 installed.
It just shows me an Frame without the transparency and even skips the code that should exit, when Translucency is not supported.

```
if (!gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(TRANSLUCENT)) {
            System.err.println(
                "Translucency is not supported");
                System.exit(0);
        }
```

It is an undecorated window and

```
counter.setOpacity(0.6f);
```

is used to create the transparency.
I cant figure out why my window is not transparent on the raspberry but on windows it is.

Comment: Which operating system is the Raspberry Pi running?

Comment: Linux version 4.4.8-v7+